# How to prove two added function are a linear mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $F$ be a field, and let $V_1$,$V_2$ be vector spaces over $F$. If $\lambda\in F$ and $g : V_1\rightarrow V_2$ is a function, then we can define the function:

$\lambda g : V_1\rightarrow V_2$ as follows: for every $x\in V_1$:

$$(\lambda g)(x) := \lambda\cdot g(x)$$

(note that, for any $x\in V_1$, we have that $g(x)$ is a vector in $V_2$,

so we can consider its scalar multiple $\lambda\cdot g(x)$ in $V_2$, and set this to be the image of $x$ under $\lambda g$).

Prove the following: if $\mu_1, \mu_2\in F$, and if $f_1, f_2$ are linear maps from $V_1\rightarrow V_2$, then:

$$\mu_1f_1 + \mu_2f_2$$

is a linear map.

So from the definition I found online if $u_1f_1+u_2f_2$ is a linear mapping then $Range(u_1f_1+u_2f_2)$ should be a subspace of $V_2$. But I'm unsure how to proceed? Should we check if it is closed under scalar multiplication, vector addition, and that it is nonempty?

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please refer to this link to format your question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You need to show that $f = \mu_1 f_1 + \mu_2 f_2$ is linear. By definition, you must show that $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$ and $f(x +y) = f(x) + f(y)$.  Use the definitions to explicitly write out what $f(x), f(y)$ evaluate to and verify the identity.